# Extract coordinates from mysql with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here I have this query:

```
SELECT json FROM `map` GROUP BY `id_parcele` ORDER BY `map`.`json` ASC
```

and I get this result:

```
 {"zoom":14,"tilt":0,"mapTypeId":"hybrid","center":{"lat":45.74270001814216,"lng":20.013914112182643},"overlays":[{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#000000","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.9,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"21.329035778926478","lng":"73.46008301171878"},{"lat":"21.40065516914794","lng":"78.30505371484378"},{"lat":"20.106233605369603","lng":"77.37121582421878"},{"lat":"20.14749530904506","lng":"72.65808105859378"}]]},{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#FFBF1A","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"49.837982453084834","lng":"15.1611328125"},{"lat":"48.63290858589532","lng":"14.4580078125"},{"lat":"47.57652571374621","lng":"16.9189453125"},{"lat":"48.574789910928864","lng":"18.6767578125"}]]},{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#FFBF1A","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"45.672363557944365","lng":"19.80757713317871"},{"lat":"45.68447721439641","lng":"19.844999313354492"},{"lat":"45.67872055615946","lng":"19.87401008605957"},{"lat":"45.67518231607532","lng":"19.906539916992188"},{"lat":"45.65076836163794","lng":"19.910917282104492"},{"lat":"45.6477683700349","lng":"19.8647403717041"},{"lat":"45.65028837377915","lng":"19.806032180786133"}]]},{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#FFBF1A","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"44.79334817513584","lng":"20.876469612121582"},{"lat":"44.785429336353964","lng":"20.876898765563965"},{"lat":"44.78579484513546","lng":"20.8815336227417"},{"lat":"44.794322726360605","lng":"20.899386405944824"},{"lat":"44.80065690817221","lng":"20.899128913879395"},{"lat":"44.79852528999652","lng":"20.887370109558105"}]]},{"type":"polygon","title":"","content":"","fillColor":"#FFBF1A","fillOpacity":0.3,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeOpacity":0.8,"strokeWeight":3,"paths":[[{"lat":"45.742071120421016","lng":"20.020394325256348"},{"lat":"45.738237366849404","lng":"20.019021034240723"},{"lat":"45.73458307545836","lng":"20.038676261901855"},{"lat":"45.73847698415968","lng":"20.04004955291748"}]]}]}
```

How I can now extrat only first coordinates from this php string... So how I can get `lat":"21.329035778926478","lng":"73.46008301171878` and put it in variable lat and lng?

Comment: You do that as with any other JSON as well, this has nothing to especially do with Mysql and PDO nor with coordinates.

Comment: Can't you store relational data instead of a serialised JSON string?  You're missing out on all the advantages offered by a *relational database management system*, including the ability to select only the fields that you want!

Comment: it easy for me to store like text becouse from 'map' table i generate google map for aplication

Comment: You can't _just_ extract some information from a JSON. You need to either read it, decode it, then access the key. This would be hardly a performance hit anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$data = json_decode($json); //Your JSON data stored in $json. This decodes the JSON string into a PHP stdClass Object
echo $data->center->lat.', '.$data->center->lng; //Outputs the lat and lng from the center object
echo $data->overlays[0]->paths[0][0]->lat.', '.$data->overlays[0]->paths[0][0]->lng; //Outputs the first lat and lng from the paths within overlays
```

Output:

```
45.742700018142, 20.013914112183
21.329035778926478, 73.46008301171878
```

Comment: yes it for center, but I need first coordinates in from paths array ???

Comment: Check the edit I made, the last line of code now show you how to do that.